# ionic 4: android permission not working after prod built

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using @ionic-native/android-permissions.
My code in app.component.ts:

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO).then(
          (result)=>{   
       if(!result.hasPermission)
       {
         this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
           [this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO, 
             this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS]
            ).then(()=>{
             // this.rootPage = HomePage;
             window.location.reload();
            });

   }
     });
```

**It is working when I do :**

ionic cordova run android

or

ionic cordova build android

or

ionic cordova build android --release

**But the app is not asking for permission if I add --prod. i.e. :**

ionic cordova run android --prod

or

ionic cordova build android --prod --release

So the device mic is not working for the app.

Comment: the code seems correct. have you added the plugin correctly as stated in the docs? is the java code part of the apk?

Comment: I don't think it's a coding issue. Because the app is working perfectly with notmal build. But for prod built I'm facing issue. Seems like its a bug in Ionic. Just wanted to check if someone have any solution.

Comment: it is on the plugin/cordova side, so not at ionic...

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and i solved it by adding permissions to config.xml
then, popup will show and ask client for permissions.
[add permissions to config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236892/4751073)

```
<platform name="android">
....
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
</config-file>
....
</platform>
```